# Is it recommended to call onDetach() & onAttach() method of the FragmentTransaction manually

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to change the font size of entire application. I have used 3 styles(small, medium,large), keeping app theme as parent. Whenever user selects the the font change button, based on selected style, I'm changing the font size of entire application. Since, for a fragment, theme has to be applied inside onCreateView(), before inflating the layout,theme will not be applied to the fragment on click of the font size change button. I need to refresh the fragment, so that it's view is recreated. I'm manually detaching the fragment and then attaching again to the activity. This destroys the fragment view and recreates it and the fragment UI is updated. My query is, is it recomended to call onDetach() & onAttach() manually?
This is how I'm refreshing the fragment:

```
private void reloadFragment() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mngr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = mngr.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
            try {
                SectionPagerAdapter adapter = ((HomeFragment) fragment).getAdapter();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.detach(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                transaction.attach(fragment);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//I'm using viewpager, so notifying it
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should not call this method as it will be heavy operation. You are basically achieve the same by handling configuration change. You can call invalidate operation , calling invalidate() might help you to achieve what is required by you.

Comment: Will it recreate the view..?

Comment: As per Android documnet : calling invalidate() .Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future.

This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

Comment: or check requestLayout() if it can help you in achieving what is required by you.

Comment: So, I should send the view of the fragment to the activity and call invalidate from activity

Comment: okay..thanks..i'll check and update you on the same

Comment: @Roll no1 tried with ur solution.It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can do this. All life circle methods can't be called manually. If you want to change `Fragment`s, you need to do like this:

```
private void reloadFragment() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mngr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = mngr.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null){
        fragment = new YourFragment();
    }
    if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
        try {
            SectionPagerAdapter adapter = ((HomeFragment) fragment).getAdapter();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(resId, fragment, tag);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//I'm using viewpager, so notifying it
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have re-edited my answer. ensure `Fragment` is not null before you call `transaction.replace(resId, fragment, tag);`. If `Fragment` is not created first time, just find it by `mngr.findFragmentByTag(tag);`

Comment: But this will create a new instance of the fragment..What about the previous fragment instance and the fragments inside the adapter? Do i need to remove the homefragment manually, before replacing?

Comment: So basically, No new fragment is recreated. same fragment is replaced in the container

Comment: If `Fragment` is created first time, then call `fragment = new YourFragment();`; if not, just find it by mngr.findFragmentByTag(tag);

Comment: Can I use findFragmentById

Comment: if you call `transaction.replace(resId, fragment, tag);`, then use `mngr.findFragmentByTag(tag);`.  `findFragmentById` is used for finding the fragment in `xml`

Comment: It's not working for me...It keeps on adding to the backstack..I want the same fragment's view to be recreated..In my case, I need to add the fragments to the back stack.So should I remove them from stack and replace it?

Comment: it's working. Actually, I was removing the fragment. but instead of recreating fragment instance , I was using the old instance, which was removed.